# HTML table layout for rows

Tags: html, css

I have two rows for my table. The top row contains some text and the bottom row contains a button. I would always like the button to stay at the bottom of the page and the top row to show scroll bars if the text is more than the space available (say if the browser window is resized).

I have been able to keep the button at the bottom using the following code but when I resize the browser it starts to overlap with the text on top. I have also not been able to get a scroll bar on the top row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .bottomRow {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum felis enim, sit amet laoreet orci imperdiet ac. Etiam viverra suscipit finibus. Donec in lectus sed odio sagittis ultrices ut sed nunc. Ut non ornare dolor. In vel nibh vestibulum, tincidunt eros eu, fermentum nunc. Integer non fermentum purus, non molestie lorem. Nunc sit amet dapibus tortor. Aliquam non felis commodo, mollis nibh non, pharetra mauris. Suspendisse nisi libero, maximus a vulputate a, condimentum et massa. Integer quis feugiat mi. In sit amet ante sed nisi facilisis commodo. Cras porttitor cursus diam in tincidunt. Phasellus nec varius dui, eget luctus mi </p> </td>
      </tr> 

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomRow"> <button>OK</button> </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Can someone please let me know how to solve these issues? If there is a better way to achieve the same effects without using table I am fine with that as well.

Thanks,

Comment: **Table cells don't have scrollbars.** You'd need to use a `div` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a scroll bar for a table cell. You would need to trick the scroll bar into displaying by having a fixed height div inside the cell with overflow-y set to scroll. Then all of your content goes inside the div.

```
<tr>
    <td> <div style='height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;'> <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum felis enim, sit amet laoreet orci imperdiet ac. Etiam viverra suscipit finibus. Donec in lectus sed odio sagittis ultrices ut sed nunc. Ut non ornare dolor. In vel nibh vestibulum, tincidunt eros eu, fermentum nunc. Integer non fermentum purus, non molestie lorem. Nunc sit amet dapibus tortor. Aliquam non felis commodo, mollis nibh non, pharetra mauris. Suspendisse nisi libero, maximus a vulputate a, condimentum et massa. Integer quis feugiat mi. In sit amet ante sed nisi facilisis commodo. Cras porttitor cursus diam in tincidunt. Phasellus nec varius dui, eget luctus mi </p> </div> </td>
  </tr>
```

I am not sure why you are having problems keeping your button at the bottom? Can you elaborate on this a little more? What is happening to your button?

Comment: I tried using div and it is working but can I get scroll bar without specifying height? I would like the height of the top row to be whatever is available in the browser window (so in that sense the height is not fixed).

I was also able to get button at the bottom but if I reduce the height of the browser window and make it too short the button starts to overlap the text on the top row. I guess it makes sense since the browser is trying to keep it at the bottom but is there some way of always keeping it below the text in the top row.

Comment: I would try setting a min-width property for the bottom row. This will make sure there is always enough room in the bottom row for your button, and keep the top from infringing on it. You will need to specify the height of the div in some way in order to have it scroll. Id try experimenting with % values instead of pixel values to accomplish what you intend. Im still not totally clear as to your end result here, it would help if i could see a sample of the page.

Comment: Please look at the following link
http://jsfiddle.net/qcuprnu9/

If you now reduce the height of the browser window, you will notice that the Ok button starts to overlap the text on the top. I would also like the scroll bar to appear after there is not enough space in the browser window to display all the text. 

Please let me know if it is still not clear.